# Where can I get free specifications of JPEG/JFIF/EXIF/etc?

Tags: jpeg, standards

I want to make a tool for myself (and maybe others if it comes out good) for low level inspection/modification of JPEG files. Sort of like [TweakPNG](http://entropymine.com/jason/tweakpng/), but for JPEGs. So far I haven't found any tool that does this.

In order to do that I need to read all the relevant specifications. Unfortunately the [official ones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPG#The_JPEG_standard) are [pretty costly](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=18902), so I'm looking for alternate sources. Is there anything you can recommend which covers as much ground as possible?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To answer my own question:

- Part 1 can be downloaded from the [W3 page](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/) and the corrigendum (which contains only patent information) from the [ITU page](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-T.81). Direct links: [Part 1](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/itu-t81.pdf), [Corrigendum](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-T.81-200401-I!Cor1/dologin.asp?lang=e&id=T-REC-T.81-200401-I!Cor1!PDF-E&type=items).
- Part 2 I cannot find, but apparently it only includes test cases for application compliance to part 1. Useful, but not necessary.
- Part 3 and its amendment detail some extensions and are again available from [ITU](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-T.84). Direct links: [Part 3](http://www.itu.int/rec/dologin_pub.asp?lang=e&id=T-REC-T.84-199607-I!!PDF-E&type=items), [Amendment](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-T.84-199904-I!Amd1/en).
- Part 4 is available from [ITU](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-T.86) as well, and details... I'm not sure yet, what. Either some more extensions and a SPIFF file format (never heard of it before); or methods for registering new extensions. Possibly both. Anyway, direct link: [Part 4](http://www.itu.int/rec/dologin_pub.asp?lang=e&id=T-REC-T.86-199806-I!!PDF-E&type=items).
- Part 5... oh, wait, there are only 4 parts! But there is a JFIF specification. That one's a bit hairy. Apparently it's at version 1.02, and was developed in good old '92, but that's pretty unofficial. ISO is still working on formalizing it, but in the meantime ECMA has already done so by simply reformatting it to their typical specification style. Anyways, the two things should be the same, as I understand. You can find them on the [W3 page](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/) and [ECMA page](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/techreports/E-TR-098.htm). Direct links: [Original](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/jfif3.pdf), [ECMA style](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-TR/ECMA%20TR-098.pdf).
- Part 6 (I like imaginary parts!) would be the EXIF standard. Accoriding to wikipedia it's never been standardized, but everyone adheres to the unoffical standard by JEIDA/CIPA. Wikipedia also had this direct link to the latest version of the spec (2010!): [EXIF 2.3](http://www.cipa.jp/std/documents/e/DC-008-2012_E.pdf)

Well, that's it folks! Happy JPEGging!

Comment: In case someone is also wondering about all the "parts": on [jpeg.org](https://jpeg.org/jpeg/) is a pretty neat summary of the parts and what they stand for

Comment: Seems (imaginary) Part 5 (ECMA version) moved also. [This seems to be be new location](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-TR/ECMA%20TR-098.pdf)

Comment: Maybe put a link to this question in the jpeg tag info page.