# What to do first to implement a JPG decoder

Tags: compression, jpeg

I need to understand JPG decompression so that I don't need other libraries that just do it.

After being able to identify the different parts of a JPG file in terms of file format, what do I need to do, understand or learn first in mathematical or algorithmic terms so I can start implementing decoding primitives?

Answer (score 3):

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8561098/1180620) to find all the specifications you need to read, and then read them. Several times. Front to back. *Then* start to implement, testing along the way often with many example jpeg files.

It wouldn't hurt to know a little bit about [fourier transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) and then the [discrete cosine transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform), and also how [Huffman codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) work. Though you could pick up much of what you need from the specifications.